# Make selected DataGridView Cell content larger

Tags: c#, view, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is coding in c#.net
My requirement is, if I select any DataGridView cell the cell content should be visible larger as a popup,  or I want to view the datagridview cell larger or fitted one when move my cursor to particular cell.

Comment: What type of content will there be in the Cells? Just text and numbers or also images, buttons etc? Also: Shall the content still be editable while enlarged?

Comment: mainly content is in text and picture and some are numerics...finally all types of contetent is there @TaW

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: My updated code does work for images, too - see the screenshots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text and numerics this may do what you need:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.RowIndex < 0 | e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
   if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected)
   {
     e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.CellBounds);
     e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), new Font(e.CellStyle.Font.FontFamily,
     e.CellStyle.Font.Size * 1.5f), SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.CellBounds.Location);
     e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

You may need to use `e.FormattedValue` instead of `e.Value` if you are using formats

You may also need to insert a test of the cell value's type..

This code this will enlarge the font by 50% while not in edit mode.

For images a different solution would be necessary - probably a popup Label or Panel; but that really depends on just what you want and what kind of images they are.. Icons I would leave alone, photos of users would profit from the enlarged display.

Of course, if the enlarged content doesn't actually fit in the Cell the popup solution would also be called for..

**Upadate**

Here is an extension which tests the Column `Value/FormattedValue` and for a `Bitmap` displays the `Image` in a popup `Label`:

```
Label imageLabel;
bool labelHide = false;                                                     //*** new

void showImageLabel(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{  
    if (labelHide)  return;                                                 //*** new
    if (imageLabel == null) imageLabel = new Label();
    imageLabel.Click += (sender, evt) => 
                        { ((Label)sender).Hide(); labelHide = true; };     //*** new

    imageLabel.Text = "";
    imageLabel.Parent = dataGridView1;
    imageLabel.Location =   e.CellBounds.Location; 
    if (imageLabel.Image != null) imageLabel.Image.Dispose();
    //Size size = ((Bitmap)e.Value).Size;                                   //*** old
    Size size = ((Bitmap)e.FormattedValue).Size;                            //*** new
    Size newSize = new Size( (int)(size.Width * 1.5f), (int)(size.Height * 1.5f));
    //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((Bitmap)e.Value, newSize);                    //*** old
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((Bitmap)e.FormattedValue, newSize);             //*** new
    imageLabel.Size = newSize;
    imageLabel.Image = bmp; 
    imageLabel.Show();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 | e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
    if (e.Value == null) { if (imageLabel != null) imageLabel.Hide(); return; }
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected)
    {
        //if (e.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))                          //*** old
        if (e.FormattedValue.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))                   //*** new
        {
            showImageLabel(e);
            e.Handled = true;                                               //*** old
            if (labelHide) labelHide = false; else e.Handled = true;        //*** new
            return;
        }
        else if (imageLabel != null) imageLabel.Hide();

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.CellBounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), 
               new Font(e.CellStyle.Font.FontFamily, e.CellStyle.Font.Size * 1.5f), 
               SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.CellBounds.Location);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (imageLabel != null) imageLabel.Hide();
}
```

You may want to adapt the Location to be e.g. centered..

**Update 2**

I have now adapted the code to the case of retrieving `Images` directly as `byte[]` from a Database.  In this case the `Type` of the `Value` Property is not `Image`. Instead one simlpy needs to check the `FormattedValue`.

If the displayed, resized `Image` is too large, it may cover the whole `Cell` and the `Cell_Painting` event won't get triggered. Therefore I have also added an one-liner for the `RowLeave` event to prevent that.

I have also added a few lines to allow the image to be clicked away.

Please change the lines I marked with //*** , add the event and check if it now works for you!

Here are two Screenshots:

[image: Image Enlarged][image: Text Enlarged]

Comment: OK, I'll update the answer with a popup that will show images enlarged a little later. What sizes are we talking about before and after?

Comment: Well it often helps to know details when implementing a solution. See my updated answer!

Comment: Can you post the code that inserts the images into the dgv?

Comment: I have added a few changes to make the code work with images you retrieve directly from a database. I hope that works; you still have not given any information how you save or load the image data or how my code failed.

Comment: Thank u for your great effort...
but didn't solve it...I have saved my image as follows my code

`byte[] imageBt = null;    
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.txtimagepath.Text,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
                imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);`

Comment: Don't worry about my efforts, I only do what I like myself. __1)__ How do you read them into the DataGridView? __2)__ Please use the Debugger: Does it ener the `showImageLabel`code? __3)__ if not: put a breakpoint on `if (e.FormattedValue.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))` and evaluate `e.FormattedValue.GetType()` !

Comment: after small modifications in my code Its working but there is a small problem with my code...
after clicking on image cell its enlarging but that is too larger which i don't want that means the image is not stretched one in our label @TaW

Comment: Look at the code: If the enlargement factors of 1.5 are too much, simply change it to what you like! The one for the image is in the showImageLabel code.

Comment: Also note: Using a factor means that if the different images have different sizes they will still be different upon enlarging them. If this is your case and you'd rather have a fixed Size, then simply use your fixed size for `newSize` to create the new `Bitmap`!